# php pass objects by reference, update class

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class which I am trying to update, been asked to demonstrate passing objects by reference, but im unsure how that relates to the class below, can anyone give me some pointers, I thought I was all ready doing that with methods like `getManegement()` If you could give some idea of what I would need to do, maybe some links or code examples that would be great

```
namespace App\Office\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Office
 * @package App\Office\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="office")
 */
class Office
{
    /**     
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $name;
    /**     
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Office\Entity\SkillSet", mappedBy="office")
     */
    public $skillSet = [];
    /**     
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Office\Entity\Management", mappedBy="office")
     */
    public $management = [];
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Office\Entity\Staff", mappedBy="office")
     */
    public $staff = [];
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSkillSets()
    {
        return $this->skillSet;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $skillSet
     */
    public function setSkillSets(array $skillSet)
    {
        $this->skillSet = $skillSet;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getManagements()
    {
        return $this->management;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $management
     */
    public function setManagements(array $management)
    {
        $this->management = $management;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStaff()
    {
        return $this->staff;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $staff
     */
    public function setStaff(array $staff)
    {
        $this->staff = $staff;
    }

    /**
     * add new skillSet, merging with existing
     * @param array $skillSet
     */
    public function addSkillSets(array $skillSet)
    {
        $this->skillSet = array_merge($this->skillSet, $skillSet);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $management
     */
    public function addManagement(int $management)
    {
        $this->management[] = $management;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $staff
     */
    public function addStaff(int $staff)
    {
        $this->staff[] = $staff;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: `public string $name;`? It is real code? You use Release Candidate?

Comment: something like Office::management or Office->mangagement??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you've been asked to do.
In case you're after passing the object properties by reference, you should adjust your code like so:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function &getSkillSets(): array
{
    return $this->skillSet;
}
```

And wherever you use it should be:

```
$myValue = &$office->getSkillSets();
```

You may read more here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

**Pay attention** that if one of the properties is already an object, using the syntax above is useless as objects being passed by reference by default in PHP.